# In android Image filter application,Getpixels and setpixels not working properly

Tags: android, image, bitmap, pixel

I am creating an image filters app in android. I am retrieving pixels from a bitmap doing some rgb work on then and setting them on another bitmap. Here is my code and it isnt working properly. please help

```
bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm1.getWidth(),
                                bm1.getHeight(), bm1.getConfig());
                        final double GS_RED = 0.299;
                        final double GS_GREEN = 0.587;
                        final double GS_BLUE = 0.114;
                        int A, R, G, B;
                        int pixel;
int[] pixels = new int[bm1.getHeight()* bm1.getWidth()];
bm1.getPixels(pixels, 0, bm1.getWidth(), 0, 0,bm1.getWidth(), bm1.getHeight());

                        for (int pix = 0 ; pix< pixels.length;pix++) {
                            A = Color.alpha(pix);
                            R = Color.red(pix);
                            G = Color.green(pix);
                            B = Color.blue(pix);
                            R = G = B = (int) (GS_RED * R + GS_GREEN * G + GS_BLUE * B);
                            pixels[pix] = Color.argb(A, R, G, B);

                        }

                        bmOut.setPixels(pixels, 0, bm1.getWidth(), 0, 0,
                                bm1.getWidth(), bm1.getHeight());
```

Comment: Define `not working properly`

Comment: the new bitmap is giving black color when i set it on an imageview. I was using getpixel and setpixel earlier. But they were slow so i tried this and it isnt working

Comment: Look at this: `R = G = B = (int) (G...` You probably better do: `R = (int) (G...` and then `G = R;` and `B = R;`

Comment: this will not make a differnce

Comment: Anyway, working pixel by pixel is an overkill. You better use ColorMatrices to apply filters. What you are trying to do is converting to GrayScale or Sepia toning. Search how to do that by using ColorMatrices.

Comment: ya that is the only option left