# How to add real time filtering effects in camera 2 API in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-gpuimageview

I am developing a camera application in android, i want to enable real time filtering effects feature in to my app,I have used GPUimage filter to add filtering effects to an image.But i don't know how to enable real time filtering effects to camera preview before taking a picture.I have used camera and camera 2 api for below lollipop version and for lollipop version.Any library is available for this ?? I am a beginner,Can anyone help?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371055/apply-custom-filters-to-camera-output

Answer (score 5):

If you need simple filters like sepia or negative you can just set CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE field in CaptureRequest instance via CaptureRequest.Builder method
`mBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE, /*your value*/);`

see [developers doc](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE) for available values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I want to add custom filtering effects like in candy cam  and retrica app .Can you help me ?

Comment: Second api isn't popular. But I'll try to find something. _All capture sessions can be used for capturing images from the camera but only reprocessable capture sessions can reprocess images captured from the camera in the same session previously._ You should start from method createReprocessableCaptureSession()

Answer (score 0):

yes I agree with the comments above, by using

```
mBuilder.set (CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE, / * your value * /);
```

Another example can use the code as below [View More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40079276/android-code-to-add-filtering-effects-using-camera2-api-in-real-time/45322434#45322434)

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set (CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_SEPIA);
```

complete documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE)