# Android code to add filtering effects using camera2 API in real time?

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am writing an android camera app using camera2 API. I want to know how to add various filtering effects i.e sepia, negative in android camera surface as a list. Please help to solve the same.

Comment: you can check out android effectFactory https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/EffectFactory.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE like this:

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_SEPIA);
```